# Как сделать определенную генерацию рандома в js

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня вопрос, вот я создаю массив рандомных чисел, а как сделать так чтобы массив заполнялся числами в интервале от 3 до 6?

```
var a = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 % 10); })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(function() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 3); }));

// Либо короче
console.log(Array(5).fill(0).map(_ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 3)));
```